# How to catch console close event in PowerShell?

Tags: c#, powershell

How do I catch the console close event in PowerShell?

I've tried adding a console control handler, and it works fine for CMD, but not in PowerShell, is there a different way in PowerShell?

Example:

```
namespace Test_ConCtrl {
    class Program {
        public enum CtrlTypes : uint { CTRL_C = 0, ... }

        public delegate Boolean ConsoleCtrl_Delegate(CtrlTypes CtrlType);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(
            ConsoleCtrl_Delegate HandlerRoutine, bool Add);

        public static Boolean My_CtrlHandler(CtrlTypes inConType) {
            switch(inConType) { ... }
        }

        static void Add_Handler() {
            ConsoleCtrl_Delegate myHandler = My_CtrlHandler;
            SetConsoleCtrlHandler(myHandler, true);
        }

        ...
```

Comment: It's not clear if this is about "console close" (i.e. PowerShell exit, in a way) or Ctrl-C events. For the PowerShell exit see my answer.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to cover both PowerShell exit and Ctrl+C, is Ctrl+C handled differently?  (I'm launching a background IO thread, and I'd like to be able to abort if the user aborts the cmdlet)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PowerShell use the engine event *PowerShell.Exiting* and specify a script blocks which process it.

Here is the example:

```
Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting -Action { "Exiting $(Get-Date)" >> C:\TEMP\log.txt }
```

Comment: Yes, that's the ticket—engine events.  I knew PowerShell eventing was key, but didn't know where to go next.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Strange, this did not work for me or a handful of people here too. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8000  Is there a way to fire off a function on closing a PowerShell console?